# invalid character at name 1

Tags: fortran

Trying to learn Fortran for a project. In a very simple program I am getting *invalid character* error.

```
program foo
   implicit none    
   integer :: n_samp
   integer :: samp_len
   integer :: x_len
   integer :: y_len
   n_samp=2
   samp_len=2
   y_len=11
   x_len=2
   real(8),dimension(n_samp,samp_len,y_len,x_len)=Yvec
end program foo
```

error generated by **GFORTRAN**

> t.f90:11.12:

```
real(8), dimension(n_samp,samp_len,y_len,x_len)=Yvec
       1
```

> Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
real(8), dimension(n_samp,samp_len,y_len,x_len) :: Yvec
```

The `::` is obligatory when specifying any attributes (as the `dimension` in your case).

As @AlexanderVoigt points out, all variable declaration must be placed in the declaration part of the code, i.e., at the beginning.

I do not recommend using `real(8)` because that is not well defined, the `8` can mean anything, it is an index to a table of kinds and different compilers can have something different at place `8` in that table. See [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter)

Comment: Also, declarations mustn't be in the main body!

Comment: Correct, I missed the previous lines.

Comment: Mhm... Maybe we should merge our posts!

Comment: Aah! double colon, so silly mistake from me. Xtremely sorry for troubling u guys.Thanks @vladimir F

Comment: Which way you mean? In high traffic tags it is common to have more answers, I think we can keep it. The priority of noticing the correct order is yours, of course.

Comment: @ashwinids Also the order of the statements, see Alexanders' answer. Nothing to be sorry about, everyone was a beginner once.

Comment: @VladimirF OK then, let's keep it.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple: You are not allowed to have declarations in the main body (that is after some instructions)! Instead, you should use parameters:

```
program foo
   implicit none    
   integer,parameter :: n_samp=2
   integer,parameter :: samp_len=2
   integer,parameter :: x_len=11
   integer,parameter :: y_len=2
   real(8),dimension(n_samp,samp_len,y_len,x_len) :: Yvec ! Add. typo here
end program foo
```

Comment: @ alexander in my actual code i'm  using the declarations as u have defined. Thanks for the input.